# How would i go about adding arguments to my discord.js commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

What would be the best way to add arguments to my discord commands?
e.g, !ban {username}
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILDS"],
});

const botOptions = {
    token: "",
    prefix: ['!','.'],
    commands: [
        {
            name: ['joined','j'],
            roles: ['@everyone'],
            channels: [],
            method: (msg) => require('./userJoined')(msg),
        },
    ],
};

Client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
    const prefix = msg.content.split('')[0];
    const commandName = msg.content.split(prefix)[1].toLowerCase();
    const checkPrefix = botOptions.prefix.some((x) => x === prefix);
    const findCommand = botOptions.commands.find(command => command.name.includes(commandName));
    if (typeof findCommand !== 'undefined' && checkPrefix) {
        const { name, roles, channels, method } = findCommand;
        const rolePermission = msg.member.roles.cache.some(role => roles.includes(role.name.toLowerCase()));
        const channelPermission = channels.includes(msg.channelId);
        if (channelPermission || channels.length === 0 && rolePermission) {
            method(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to add args (arguments) you should first split the message into an array

```
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
```

Now you just have an array full of arguments, the first argument in the messageArray variable is basically the command which is being executed, after that the rest are just the message args.

```js
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0]; // getting the command, this line can be removed
    let args = messageArray.slice(1)
```

In the example above we sliced the messageArray variable at its 2nd element which is the first argument of the message (not including the cmd).

So here is a small example how this works
`!mix 3845345343 4353943`

`3845345343` being `args[0]`
`4353943` being `args[1]`

and so on if you have more args